# Is there a way to improve the thumbnail quality of links posted to facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, image-quality

I'm trying to post a link on Facebook that directs the user to a page on a website. I have configured the page to have the og:image and the og:image:secure_url properties holding the link to the image and the og:image:width and og:image:height are set to 1280 and 720 respectively (the real dimensions of the picture). The dimensions are larger than the ones recommended by facebook [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/images/). Also, the image is of type jpg so the og:image:type property is set to image/jpeg. 
 
The issue I'm facing is that the thumbnail which appears in the facebook post is very blurry and it is downsized to about 500 by 260 pixels. To improve the quality of the thumbnail I have tried the following:
* resizing the original image to the facebook recommendations (1200 x 630) and modifying the og:image:width and og:image:height
* uploading it in different formats (.png, .jpg, .webp) and changing the og:image:type  accordingly
* sharpening the original image in an attempt to make the thumbnail look less blurry
None of these attempts seemed to improve the thumbnail quality, even though the original image looks very good.
Here is a list of all the tags I'm using:

```html
<meta property="og:title" content="The title">
    <meta property="og:image"
        content=https://siteAddress />
    <meta property="og:image:secure_url"
        content=https://siteAddress />
    <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="1280">
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="720">
```

Is there a way to control how the facebook crawler sets the quality of the thumbnails? What else could I apply to the original image to obtain a less blurry thumbnail? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There’s no Facebook setting for image quality. Can you edit your question to include all of your Open Graph meta tags? It’s easier to provide a recommendation if the code is available.

Comment: I see you added a generic list of meta tags (but not your list). Your list is missing the quote marks around the URLs, which would cause the image to not load (Facebook would use another image on your page). Have you tried running your page through Facebook’s [Sharing Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)?